# Different TestCases into the same Class, how to parallelize only some of them?

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm doing some tests on a webpage using selenium and nunit.

I've got a class that contains 8 differtent TestCases. 3 Of them can run in parallel, the other 4 cannot because they do operations on a DB and they could interfere each other.

Is there a method to tell nunit that some tests can run in parallel and some other (in the same class) don't?
I've tried to deal it by giving to each testCase the attribute [Parallelizable] and those who cannot run in parallel with [NonParallelizable] but no parallelization has been done.
I've tried to read the nunit documentation and it says that these attribute can be applied to method and classes, so i assume TestCases too, i'm assuming wrong?

Is there any method to to tell nunit that some tests can run in parallel and some other (in the same class) don't?

Comment: IMO the bigger problem is that your Database can't be used from multiple threads. Instead of trying to run some in parallel and some not, it's my opinion that you should try and make your DB thread safe. Or better yet, provide independent databases for each unit test

Comment: Yes, i agree with u, but i don't have the possibility of doing this..That's why i'm looking for that solution

Answer (score 1):

In NUnit, it's not possible to finely control which tests may run in parallel with one another, although such a feature has been discussed in the past.

The simplest solution is to make those tests non-parallelizable. In most cases, a few non-parallelized tests will not have a large effect on performance.

The alternative, as you have recognized is to re-organize the tests into separate fixtures.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, i've managed by creating different classes.. What do you mean by using separate fixtures? Sorry for the noob question, but i'm at my first week of test automation and i'm still very poor in knowledbe about that

Comment: In NUnit a fixture is a class that contains tests. So you've done what I suggested. :-)